# Calling method or setting value directly using the same keyword

Tags: javascript

I want to make a class where I can call the method or set a variable in a class using the same keyword. I kinda don't think it is possible, but if there is a way, or any work around please share. Here is an example code.

```
class myClass {
  text(text) {
    this.innerText = text;
  }
}

let a = new myClass();

//I want this to work
a.text(2);

//I also want this to work
a.text = 2;
```

Comment: Where is `innerText` declared?

Comment: I'm sure it is possible to get both `a.text(2)` and `a.text = 2` to work, but you most certainly then won't be able to use `a.text` to read the value `2`, only `a.text()` would work then. But the question is why do you want to do that? Because that will break any expectation of how an object will/should work and as of that it hurts maintainability badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically you can do that, but then getting the value back has to take another route:

```js
class Test {
  something=1;
  set stuff(x){
    this.something=x;
  }
  get stuff(){
    return function(x){this.something=x;};
  }
  get check(){
    return this.something;
  }
};

let a=new Test;
console.log(a.check);
a.stuff=2;
console.log(a.check);
a.stuff(3);
console.log(a.check);
console.log("---");
console.log("a.stuff: "+a.stuff);
```

Because here

- `a.stuff=2;` calls the [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)
- `a.stuff(3);` actually [gets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) `a.stuff`, and then invokes it `()`, with `3`

So both the getter and setter are occupied with setting the field behind (`something`), thus "really" reading it needs some other name (`check` here).

Answer (score 0):

Your hunch is correct. Because there can be only one element called `text` on a class, it can either be a function or a property. You cannot have it both ways. Assigning `a.text = 2` as you've done above will overwrite `a`'s `text` function definition.

If you're not aware, it is possible to create a property `text` in such a way that it will set `innerText` the way your function does:

```
class myClass {
  get text() { return this.innerText; }
  set text(val) { this.innerText = val; }
}
```

```
let a = new myClass();
a.text = 'test';
console.log(a.innerText) // -> 'test'
```